# Email match regex returning undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

On my Rails app I only allow Berkeley.edu users to sign up at the moment, but will soon add University of Washington. what I'm trying to do is create a way to recognize which email domain their email is, UW.edu or Berkeley.edu, and set the school attribute in the User model based on that.

I mostly have it down I think but I'm getting a bit stuck. So in User.rb I have a before_save :match hook, and then a match method that looks like this:

```
def match
    matches = self['email'].match(/((?<berk>.*?berkeley\.edu))/i)
    self.school = 'berk' if matches['berkeley'].present?
  end
```

The error I'm getting looks like this:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #10):


  8 def match
  9  matches = self['email'].match(/((?<berk>.*?berkeley\.edu))/i)
  10  self.school = 'berk' if matches['berkeley'].present?
    end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you looking for `matches['berkeley']` when you regex uses `?<berk>`? And what do you expect `String#match` to return for `pancakes@example.com`? Also, your regex is a lot looser than you want it to be, I'd recommend a real and well tested email address parser over hand-rolled regexes, email addresses are a lot more complicated than most people think.

Comment: be aware that if I went out and bought the domain "myberkeley.educationisgreat.com" it would match your regex too.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely check what self['email'] is. From your error, it appears that it is nil.

Also, line 10 should read `self.school = 'berk' if matches['berk'].present?` since you are storing it in the match data under 'berk':

```
[4] pry(main)> e.match(/((?<berk>.*?berkeley\.edu))/i)['berkeley']
IndexError: undefined group name reference: berkeley
from (pry):4:in `[]'
[5] pry(main)> e.match(/((?<berk>.*?berkeley\.edu))/i)['berk']
=> "phil@berkeley.edu"
```

e in my case is "phil@berkeley.edu".